# Zoom effect to another view

Tags: php, animation, web, effect, zooming

Can I, by using PHP make a zoom effect that will zoom in the part where I clicked and visually add a new view to that section? What I want is to have a background picture and some clickable areas, when user click on a specific clickable part, that part will zoom in to a certain degree and then display that part in enlarged view and also add another view upon it.

What I want is something similar to http://www.naranglardor.com (click on the blood stains(and no, I'm not in a satanic cult, that book is a fiction about something)).

Is this possible with PHP?

Thankful for tip or any direction towards approaching this.

Best regards,

Gabriel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, you cannot** achieve that with PHP.

[PHP](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php) is a server-side scripting language, meaning that the code is executed on the server.

What you need to achieve such effects is a client-side language, like JavaScript better utilized through [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

**To point you into some sort of direction, you can check this links out:**

[Codrops Tutorials](http://tympanus.net/codrops/category/tutorials/) - Excellent for jQuery based animations and effects.

[Learning jQuery](http://www.learningjquery.com/) - Tips and tricks with jQuery.

Comment: Ah, that answers my question. Answered.